# jquery read all document events

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello how to get all attached events to document ?
I tried this but it doesn't work

```
    $.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{
        var events = jQuery(document).data("events");
        //var isExistGlobalEvents = jQuery.data(jQuery(document).get(0), 'events').click;
        if (!events) {
            AddGlobalEvents();
            // has loadedmetadata event
        }
```

Comment: Why would you need this? It sounds like there could be a better way to achieve whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes you are right I know this way, but I need to know this.